# How to edit html of parent tag using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, liquid

I'm using Shopify to host my online store, and have added some images to a page which I would like to be static.

Unfortunately Shopify wants to turn these into lightboxes using fancybox, and it is turning the image I supply into the child of a link tag. So in the code that I can edit, I see this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
 <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" alt="elle decoration magazine" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 25px;"/>
</div>
```

but when I load the page it has done this:

```
<div style="text-aling: center;">
 <a href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" class="fancyboximg">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" alt="elle decoration magazine" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 25px;"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

I would rather not edit the original file that is causing this behaviour, because it's being used site-wide, and I know I will cause something else to stop working as intended if I do.

Is it possible to remove the link tag retrospectively?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) jQuery function.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancyboximg > #remove-fancy').unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="text-aling: center;">
  <a href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" class="fancyboximg">
    <img id="remove-fancy" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" alt="elle decoration magazine" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 25px;"/>
  </a>

  <a href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" class="fancyboximg">
    <img  src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1333/8187/t/6/assets/ASI_elle_decoration.jpg?9949612793051485599" alt="elle decoration magazine" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 25px;"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to localize that script to a single div? Currently it's causing images elsewhere on the page to disappear.

Comment: For it you should have to give a unique id to current img and the selector will be with id and the unwrap will occur for that particular div only.

Comment: Would that look something like this? Sorry, I'm quite inexperience in jquery... $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancyboximg > #remove-fancy').unwrap();
});

Comment: Yes that's correct. Please check in updated snippet as well. In first image I have set the id so the link has unwrapped from first image and the link has not been wrapped up from the second one.

Comment: Im still having trouble with targetting the ID. There might be something else overriding it, but I can't tell what it is. I can see your example works well though. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: To avoid the risk of `id` duplication you could simple do `$('.fancyboximg > img').unwrap();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the jQuery unwrap function.

```
var imgTags = $( "img" );    
if ( imgTags.parent().is( "a" ) ) { imgTags.unwrap(); }
```

[Link to jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Comment: Thanks @christiangh, I managed to get it working with this. Is it possible to mark two answers correct?